# Function key on my acer laptop is always pressed

Tags: function-keys

While typing normal keys I have to press fn (function key) as it seems that the function key is pressed all the time.

What do I have to do to turn the function key off and it trigger it only when I press on it.

Comment: It sounds like the key is stuck.  Try carefully removing the key, and clean it, and underneath it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, after doing some random key pressing!

Infact there was key <kbd>numLk</kbd>, so i again press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>numLk</kbd> and my keys started working properly.

Comment: I had the same issue... weird though that it gets "pressed" automatically at reboot..

Comment: I had this issue after using a USB keyboard for a while and using NumLock on it. Maybe Ubuntu should automatically switch between On and Off when changing keyboards.

Comment: Same here. had to click Fn+Esc (where the "lock" symbol appears), Latitude E7470

Answer (score 13):

Try to press ESC(FnLk)+Fn. This help for my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS + Lenovo Thinkpad E540.

Comment: What is FnLk .?

Comment: @Tim FnLk is Function Lock. This really does apply to some laptop keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a setting in your BIOS for this. I know that some laptops use the F1-F12 keys for special functions and require the function key to be pressed for normal key use. Try running your BIOS setup while booting and look for an option you can change.

Comment: Okay I will look into it!

Comment: I have checked into the BIOS for keyboard/function key setting, But I didn't get any.

Moreover I found while entering the password at startup. Normal keys are working, But after logged into, pressing the same key result as if that key is pressed with function key.

Is there some way I can fix it?

Comment: Any help please??

Answer (score 1):

Lately I've been having the same problem across Ubuntu 10.04 (LinuxCNC edition), 11.04, and the late stable 12.04. I have an Acer Aspire 4535. The combo <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>numLk</kbd> doesn't work and my BIOS doesn't have any key customization, and then I've found the error message about Compiz in Ubuntu 12.04 and tried reinstall it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

And now the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is back under control. I almost thought this was a hardware problem. I'm a newbie using Ubuntu so i don't know what actually happened to Compiz, it just works now.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> solves the problem for me (ASUS laptop).

Comment: click Fn key and while clicking on that click Esc key. Clicking both at the same time did not work for me. Thank you.